# Trouble with data synchronization and writable per-user subdirectories using EFS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-efs

I used [this EFS walkthrough](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/accessing-fs-nfs-permissions-per-user-subdirs.html) to mount my EFS and enable writable per-user subdirectories on my EC2 instance.

According to the documentation, `All files and subdirectories the user creates in their home directory are then created on the Amazon EFS file system`. But when I look through the user directories in `/mnt`, they do not all contain the files and subdirectories that are in the corresponding user home directories.

How can I ensure that what's on the EFS is the same as what's in the users' home directory? Because if I unmount and remount the EFS, I will lose data.

Comment: When you say "they do not all contain the files and subdirectories" I assume some are working? Is there any pattern? Have you rebooted the instance to flush the disk cache to force writing?

Comment: @Tim yeah, some user directories look okay. Others are empty. I’m worried if I reboot, I’ll loose that user data.

Comment: There's no doubt a Linux command to flush the disk cache. Also, I think that tutorial actually replaces the home drives with EFS, it's not sync'd or copied, it's mounted directly in the Linux file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `mount -t nfs4` to see that some EFS directories simply didn't get mounted. I copied the missing content to the proper EFS directory and then re-mounted them. This seems to have solved the issue.

Mounting the directories didn't produce an error the first time around, so I'd recommend double-checking that all directories have been properly mounted.